# How to display an image in flutter without changing its scale or aspect ratio

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget

i ma trying to display an image in my flutter app without changing its properties. Given that i have images where some have longer width than height and vice versa. i have tried not using height and width properties but it still gets to affect some images .

Here is my code

```
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Stack(
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Image.network(
                                  widget.post.imageUrls[0],
                                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.3,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width: screenWidth(context)*0.2,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                    color:Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.4),
                                  ),
                                  child: CountDownTimer(
                                    secondsRemaining: secs,
                                    whenTimeExpires: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        hasTimerStopped = true;
                                      });
                                    },
                                    countDownTimerStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                                      fontSize: 14.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]
                          ),

            ...other elements in my column below ...
```

What widget can i use to display these images safely.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want the image to be show as big as it is and keep also its scale?

If so then you can use the **BoxFit.none** which will keep the aspect ratio and size. You can read more here:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html

But one thing bothers me, why dou you have set the **height to be 30% of the screen** but still ask to have the image not resized (reduced to 30% height of the screen)?